# WordPress custom ajax login not working on mobile browsers

Tags: ajax, login, wp-signup

I have a custom Ajax login/signup form which logs the user in and invokes `location.reload()` if the request is successful.

My Ajax login works perfectly in desktop browsers using only the `wp_signon` call. I'm unable to get it to work in mobile browsers where it seems the auth cookie is not being set.

I've tried many variations using the following functions and nothing seems to work in mobile browsers. No errors are returned (WP_Error) and the login seems successful but when the `location.reload()` triggers in the mobile browser the user is not logged in.

```
wp_signon(array(
       'user_login' => $email,
       'user_password' => $password,
       'remember' => true
      ));
do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
```

I don't understand why my login form works perfectly in desktop browsers but doesn't work in mobile devices.

Comment: Researched more and my desktop browser was on https. seems to work fine in SSL, is it that the auth cookie is not dropped on the browser is the website isn't secure?

Comment: If the cookie or WordPress urls aren't set up to respond appropriately to http vs https, it can cause problems. You can use `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` to force only the admin to use https.